# RADIUS server work flow

Tags: networking, radius, 802.1x, freeradius

I need to clarify network workflow of RADIUS solution.
Does the NAS ask each single request first from the RADIUS server? I know that RADIUS can perform authentication and accounting, but I don't know whether the NAS asks each single request from RADIUS first or not?

Comment: I hope question more clear now

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator. In the terminology of the RADIUS protocol specification, NAS means "Network Access Server". In RADIUS terminology, the NAS is the RADIUS client, and the AAA server is the RADIUS server. This use of the acronym NAS likely predated the rise of "Network-Attached Storage".

Comment: *Does the NAS ask each single request first from the RADIUS server?* What requests do you have in mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a device first connects to a NAS, the NAS uses RADIUS to authenticate the device before it allows the device to fully connect and pass other traffic. In many setups, that's the only time the connecting device has to be authenticated for that session. As long as the device stays connected to the NAS (that is, as long as its session stays up), it will not get reauthenticated.

However, if the NAS or the RADIUS server is configured to require periodic reauthentication during active sessions, then that might happen too. It might be done, say, every 15 minutes or every hour. The exact reauthentication interval is usually a setting that the administrator of the NAS or the RADIUS server can configure.

An earlier revision of your Question made it sound like you were asking if the NAS authenticates the device on *every packet*, to which the answer is a strong "NO!". It would be excessively slow and far too much traffic/load to have to exchange a handful of RADIUS packets for every real data packet. That's why the authentication is per-session (with possible periodic reauthentication intevals on the order of several minutes to hours), not per-packet.

Comment: so, suppose if 2 client authenticated to network and obtained IP and one of them disconnected after 1 min, If second client changes his IP addres to which is disconnected client (i am not sure in this case current client will start from NEW state or not ) Radius will ask again auth credentials or not ? or Radius will pass this IP as already authenticated user ?

Comment: from my point of view if change device IP address manually it will change STATE to "NEW". if like that then everything is clear, NAS can ask auth credential again in NEW state. But if not change TCP/UDP state then how  NAS avoid this hack ?

Comment: @FariZ RADIUS authenticates devices making Link-layer (layer 2) connections to the NAS. IP addresses are a layer higher, at the Network layer (layer 3). You could conceivably change your IP address without ending your link-layer session, so that would not trigger a reauthentication. But if you bring down your link-layer connection to the NAS and bring it back up, you will get reauthenticated.

Comment: @FariZ If this answer successfully resolved your question, please click the outline of a checkmark next to this answer to mark it as resolved.